# What's the distinction between an algebra and a Lie algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, algebras

An algebra, as far as I know, is closely related to a group with a family of functions being closed under addition, scalar multiplication and then the product of any two functions in the family.

Then there is this separate term I came across on Wikipedia called a [Lie Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) which doesn't look related. But is there a relation? Does a Lie algebra need to satisfy the regular algebra axioms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstractly, both an *algebra* and a *Lie algebra* are vector spaces equipped with a multiplication. The difference is in the kind of multiplication they are equipped with. An *algebra* is often called by it's full name, an *associative algebra*, since the multiplication is *associative*:
$$a(bc) = (ab)c\,.$$
For a Lie algebra, the multiplication has to be *skew-symmetric* and follow the *Jacobi identity*, which respectively mean:
$$
xy=-yx
\qquad
x(yz)+z(xy)+y(zx)=0$$

Then, based on what you said at first, it might be helpful to mention that sometimes folks use the word *algebra* much more generally to mean "a ring acting centrally on a ring" or something similar to that.

Comment: So a Lie algebra can't have just a regular ab=ba symmetry? What about Lie groups? 2x2 matrices don't necessarily satisfy this property but somehow 2x2 matrices are very involved in Lie algebras.

Comment: @askmorequestionsagain2 Almost never. A Lie algebra can only have usual symmetry if the multiplication is zero ($xy=0$ for all elements of the Lie algebra), or the base field has characteristic two, in which case $1 = -1$.

Comment: @askmorequestionsagain2 And Lie groups, though related to Lie algebras, are are different animals entirely. So no they don't have those properties.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add that a pretty useful example is the vector space $\mathbb R^3$ over the field $\mathbb R$ where the extra operation is the cross product (also know as the vector product) which usefulness lays in the great number of geometrical constructions as well as of the vector-calculus processes.